# JSON_CONTAINS doesn't recognize my column mysql v.8.0.17 laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, mysql-8.0

I have to do a query similar to this:

`SomeModel::whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(column, '', '$.a')")->get();`

`column contains JSON  *{"a":null}*;`

With mysql version 5.7 everything works fine, i get empty collection but on a database on digitalocean which is mysql v8.0.17 i get this error:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[22032]: <>: 3141 Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_contains: "The document is empty." at position 0. (SQL: select * from 'table' where JSON_CONTAINS(column, '', '$.a'))'

I'm stuck on this for days, please help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is empty string that you are passing as argument.

Try:

```
SomeModel::whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(column, null, '$.a')")->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I put null it works. What confused me is that it worked like this on 5.7.28.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you want to search a json field inside a json column, so you need a json array for that an not just an empty value.

Try something like:

```
SomeModel::whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(`column`, cast('[]' as json), '$.a')")->get();
```

Also use `` for your column names.

Since you are using laravel 5.7, you could also use the eloquent functions that are shipped with laravel like:

```
SomeModel::whereJsonContains('your_json_field','your_value')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :) I'm actually using laravel 5.6 so I don't have this eloquent function, but casting also did the job. Thank you.